# What's the correct pronoun

Tags: pronouns

Can I say

> I left the documents on your desk, take **them**

Or should I say

> I left the documents on your desk, take **it**

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Of course, you should say:

> I left the **documents** on your desk. Take **them**.

You need the pronoun *them* because it refers back to a plural noun which, in this case, is *documents* (plural nouns represent things that are more than one in number). The pronoun *it* is used for things that are singular (one in number):

> I left the **document** on your desk. Take **it**.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is entirely ambiguous because you haven't specified what the person is being told to take:

> I left the **documents** on your desk. Take **them**. [The documents.]
>   I left the documents on your **desk**. Take **it**. [The desk.]

The above two sentence pairs are both grammatical barring any context.

However, they are only *both* correct until more context is provided as to the noun that is being referred to; once the referent is identified, then only one of the sentence pairs will be correct—and the intended meaning will determine the appropriate syntax.